# Spring boot spring data mongodb replica set configuration

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm having problem connecting to db which is being recently implemented replica set.

There is two ways to connect, one is through the URI and other is to create mongo client with server address and credential list

None of them are working ,

```
     MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(getDatabaseURI()+getDatabaseName()+"?replicaSet=test-replset&readPreference=primary&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA1");
     MongoClient client = new MongoClient(uri);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer

```
    List<MongoCredential> credentialsList = new ArrayList<MongoCredential();
    credentialsList.add(MongoCredential.createCredential("USER",
            "DB_NAME", "PASSWORD".toCharArray()));


        client = new MongoClient("LIST<ServerAddress> YOURSERVERLIST" ,
                credentialsList,
                MongoClientOptions.builder()
                        .connectTimeout(TIME_OUT)
                        .readPreference(ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred())
                        .build()
        );
```

Comment: Could you please share how to configure this as bean ? Please share whole code